Feasibility of Supercapacitor Design Using Etched Brass-Coated Copper Wires
I'm working on designing a supercapacitor and would appreciate any insights into its feasibility and potential challenges.
Design Overview:
My plan involves creating multi-layer coils where the anode and cathode alternate, separated by a dielectric material. The electrodes are made from wires consisting of a copper core coated with brass. I intend to etch the brass layer using an electric current to remove the zinc, leaving behind a porous copper surface. This process aims to significantly increase the surface area of the electrodes, enhancing the capacitance.
For the dielectric, I'm considering a meltable material that, once solidified, would provide structural support to the porous copper without impeding its electrical properties.
Questions and Concerns:
Is it practical to create a high-surface-area porous copper structure by etching zinc from brass in this manner?
What dielectric materials can we use here?
Is this design practical overall?
Visual Aid:
Below is a cross-sectional diagram of the wire after erosion:

Eager to hear your thoughts, suggestions, or any experiences you might have with similar designs.
Thank you for your time and expertise!

While whiskers have a lot of area, they aren't plates in opposition to
a second conductor; the part of the whisker area that faces other whiskers
in contact with the same capacitor terminal, is irrelevant to the energy stored by the two-terminal capacitor.   Energy storage in a capacitor requires the
volume of insulation between terminals to  have high electric field
stress.  The 'area-and-distance' formulae that apply to parallel plates do not apply to the proposed geometry.
A second issue, is that those whiskers are conductive, and might come loose
and create a short circuit.   If they were to do so, the resulting current
could melt or evaporate them.
